# Fish is running abbreviations in config.fish

Tags: fish

I just learned about abbr and so I’m switching all my aliases from separate functions to just `abbr` invocations. I assumed based on the documentation that I could add these all into `~/.config/fish/config.fish` by putting them in side an `if status --is-interactive` check, but when I start up fish I see it attempting to run several commands. Any ideas how this would be happening? Below is a minimal version of my `config.fish` that reproduces the error.

```
set PATH ~/.node/bin $PATH
set PATH ~/bin/ $PATH
set -x NODE_TLS_REJECT_UNAUTHORIZED 0
set JAVA_HOME $JDK_HOME
set GRADLE_USER_HOME ~/.gradle

if status --is-interactive
    abbr --add -g build_clean ./gradlew clean build copyEar && docker-compose down --remove-orphans && docker-compose up --build
end
```

This results in

```
~/.config/fish/config.fish (line 8): The file 'docker-compose' is not executable by this user
    abbr --add -g build_clean ./gradlew clean build copyEar && docker-compose down --remove-orphans && docker-compose up --build
                                                               ^
from sourcing file ~/.config/fish/config.fish
    called during startup
```

Comment: The `&&` is separating docker-compose from abbr. This is a case where you'd better stick to functions.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Quote the abbreviation expansion if it contains shell meta chars. Having said that the abbreviation you're having trouble with would seem better suited to be a function. Abbreviations are best suited for situations where you want something very short to expand into a command of modest length that you execute a lot and want the expansion in your history rather than a function name. For example, `gcm` => `git checkout master`.